# How to show $m+n = n+m$ in the set of Naturals with zero.

Tags: peano-axioms

I understand the axioms defined on the set of natural numbers that $m+0:=m$ and that $m+n’:=(m+n)’$.
Where does the commutativity come into this?

Comment: In particular, the problem I have is proving the base step where n=0. I do not know how to show that commutes.

Comment: Prove m+ 0= 0+ m as a separate induction.  If m= 0, that is 0+ 0= 0+ 0 which is obviously true.  Further, 0'= 0+1= 1 while 1+ 0= 1 from the definition of 0.  Now suppose that for some m= k, k+ 0= 0+ k.  Then k'+ 0= (k+1)+ 0= k+ (1+ 0)= k+ 1= k'= 0+ k'.